# PHP SQL loop- excluding code from last in loop

Tags: php

Here is my code example below. I am using MDPF. Everything generates just fine but because I have the page break in the loop I always have an extra blank page at the end. What can I do to exclude the page break from the final record.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT xxxxxxx FROM table WHERE id='$id1';");
if(!$results){die();}
if($results){ 
    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

        $t = $results->num_rows;
        $i = 0;
        if (++$t != $i) {
            $mpdf->WriteHTML("<pagebreak>");
        }

    }
    $mpdf->Output('thepdf.pdf', 'D');
}
```

Comment: You could move the pagebreak above the output to mpdf and skip the first iteration.

Comment: It looks like you're fetching an object and then not doing anything with it? (I mean, `$obj` is never used inside your `while` loop.)

Comment: Don't Panic - its actually several hundred lines, I just simplified it and only has what is relevant to question

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Never mind then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost done. Just a few wrong places of the syntaxes. You should initial $t and $i out of loop. Also, a simple change in your if logic:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT xxxxxxx FROM table WHERE id='$id1';");
if(!$results){die();}
if($results){ 
    $t = $results->num_rows;
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
    {
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

        if (--$t > 0) {
            $mpdf->WriteHTML("<pagebreak>");
        }

    }
    $mpdf->Output('thepdf.pdf', 'D');
}
```

Comment: Defining variables outside the loop fixed the issue -    $t = $results->num_rows always equaled 1 inside the loop - Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `$i` isn't really needed. When `$t` gets to zero it will evaluate as false.